# Kubuntu doesn't show logout or shut down or restart prompt dialog?

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown, logout

My main installation is Kubuntu. Then, recently I installed several others DEs like Gnome-flashback, Unity, GNOME 3, and XFCE.

At the beginning, everything is okay. But now, I've got a little problem with logout and shutdown/restart. Normally, when I try to logout by clicking logout option in the Kickoff, a new prompt dialog will appear to confirm the logout. But, now I don't see the prompt anymore.

I have two user account in my Kubuntu. The problem is not occured in the other user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, the trouble maker is the file `/home/user/.kde/share/config/ksmserverrc`. Just remove it and reboot Kubuntu.